# mongoDB option usecreateindex is not supported

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

im tryng to connect to a mongoDB database but when i start the code i get the messagge
Errore nella connessione al database: MongoParseError: option usecreateindex is not supported
tats the part my code got the error

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Messages from "./model/dbMessages.mjs";

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use(express.json());
//database
const connectionDbUrl = "mongodb+srv://f:password.@cluster0.nn1vaf7.mongodb.net/discuss?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(connectionDbUrl, 
    {
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }, 
    (err)=>{
        if(!err) console.log("Mongo DB has Connect succesfully");
    });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once( "open", function() {
    console.log("CONNESOOO");
});
db.on("error", function(error) {
    console.error("Errore nella connessione al database:", error);
});
```

i tried to chenge the link to mongoDB in every way and also installed the 6.10.0 version of mongoose but still not working